# How to set as constant velocity speed ? (Cocos2d-x)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

How to set velocity speed as constant

spriteBody->setVelocity(Vec2(100,300));
this is slow down after a while

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for what you need. You can move using actions:

```
auto action = MoveBy::create (duration, Vec2(100,300));
spriteBody->runAction (action);
```

When you want to stop later:

```
sprite->stopAction (action);
```

You can manually control velocity in update funtion:

```
void update (float dt)
{
    //slow down speed
    //velocityVector is a Vec2 of velocity
    //slowAmount is a float which contains amount to slow in 1 second
    unitVector = velocityVector;
    unitVector.normalise();
    velocityVector -= unitVector *  slowAmount * dt;

    //adjust position
    sprite->setPosition (getPosition () + velocityVector * dt);
}
```

Or you can use physics body:

```
sprite->getPhysicsBody()->applyForce(Vec2(100, 300));
```

If you want the physics body to slow down set the friction of the material for the physicsbody

```
auto material = PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT; 
material.density = 1.0f;
material.restitution = 0.7f;
material.friction = 0.5f; //set friction here
sprite->setPhysicsBody(PhysicsBody::createBox(sprite->getContentSize(), material));
```

More details on how to handle physics and setup:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics

Comment: watch video , not for me of you are solution , I am making physicis game :/

Comment: Edited my answer to include physics

Comment: Thanks for answer but What is "velocityVector" and "slowFactor" ? Can you tell me with details ?

Comment: velocityVector is Vec2 variable which you can change to control velocity/speed. slowFactor is a float variable that contains a percentage by which you want the vector to slow. a slowFactor of 90% would be 0.9f.

Comment: btw if your question was answered you can close your question by marking the accepted answer.

Comment: Which solution did you try? For manual control solution, did you scheduleUpdate ()? And set the velocityVector start value?

Comment: I tried second solution and my sprite did not show and i did scheduleUpdate (). I set velocityVector start value

Comment: Your velocity might be too much

Comment: I set (1,3) to velocity :(

Comment: Try the new solution

Comment: I got this error " error: invalid operands of types 'void' and 'float' to binary 'operator*'"

Comment: this did not work , problem same, my sprite did not show :(

Comment: I see that you are using physics. Either remove the physics or use the third option I have provided above for physics.

Answer (score 1):

here is a constant moving ball example:

```
// Layer::init()
// center is just winSize / 2

auto ball = Node::create();
ball->setPosition(center);
auto circleBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(10.f, PhysicsMaterial(1.f, 1.f, 1.f));
ball->setPhysicsBody(circleBody);
circleBody->setGravityEnable(false);
// change the direction so we don't keep watching it bouncing at the same direction up and down
circleBody->setVelocity(center + Vec2(500, 500));
this->addChild(ball);


void GameScene::update(float dt) {

    auto body = ball->getPhysicsBody();

    float constantSpeed = 500.f;

    body->setVelocity(body->getVelocity().getNormalized() * constantSpeed);
}
```

doing it this way will always maintain a constant speed no matter what !!